# How can I insert an image in this map function code by React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building imagebox by using map function but don't know how to connect two files. It doesn't show the image, it just shows the direction of the image.

[image: view shows like this]

```
import React from "react";
import "../navi.css"

function NaviIcon (props) {
  return (
    <div id="NaviIcon">
      <span>{props.image}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NaviIcon;
```

I imported this file to below file

```
import React from "react";
import NaviIcon from "./NaviIcon";
import "../navi.css";

const image = [
  {
   image : "./images/shopping-cart.png"
  },
  {
    image : './images/bell.png'
  },
  {
    image : './images/user.png'
  },
];

function NaviIconList (props) {
  return (
    <div id="NaviIconList">
      {image.map((image) => {
        return (
          <NaviIcon image={image.image} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default NaviIconList;
```

it works well if the items of array are not images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace the `span` with an `img` tag:

From this:

```html
 <span>{props.image}</span>
```

To this:

```html
 <img src={props.image} />
```

And **never forget** the [`alt` attribute](https://help.siteimprove.com/support/solutions/articles/80000863904-accessibility-image-alt-text-best-practices) whenever dealing with images. It's crucial for accessibility and UX.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `<img>` tag inside `NaviIcon`.

```
<img src={props.image}/>
```